# Accepting user input in Visual studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm running Visual Studio with python Extension 3.7.4 (64bit)
I am unable to run a code in integrated terminal which requires user input. 
Note that this runs fine in external terminal but when i run it in the integrated terminal(debug console)(in pic) and enter any input it gives the error 
"Unable to find thread for Evaluation"

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKVSg.png)
[External Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soCaX.png)

I have tried installing and re installing Visual studio code

```
print("enter something")
s = input()
print("You wrote:",s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Debug Console" in VS Code is written to by debug adapters, and the text box at the bottom is used for expression evaluation (what you type here goes to a debug adapters `evaluateRequest` method).

The "Unable to find thread for Evaluation" messge is because "global evaluation" is not supported - the Python extension will only evaluate expressions when there is an active thread. If you hit a breakpoint and then type `1+1` in this box, you'll see it print `2`:

[image: Python expression evaluation]

If you need to interact with stdin for your process, you should run it in the integrated terminal. No debug extension is going to route the input from the Debug Console to stdin of the debugee, because it's the same method that is invoked for hovers and the Watch pane.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine for me when I tested your code within my vscode terminal
This guide will help you ensure your vscode environment is properly configured:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: By terminal you do mean Debug console right? (I edited just to be clear)

Comment: I was able to run in both the debug console and terminal. Can you run it by right clicking within the file and selecting "Run Python File in Terminal"?

Comment: Posting your .launch config (gear icon next to the run button in debugger) might be useful

Comment: Yes i can run it by selecting "Run Python File in Terminal"... and maybe i might have messed up my launch config ..where can i post it ?

Comment: ensure your launch config matches the code shown here: {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: this section of the vscode python guide covers debugger setup: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_troubleshooting

Comment: Yeah actually i checked that link before still no luck ..thanks